# Authenticate using LDAP

Tags: php, ssh, ldap, ldapconnection

I have an ssh access to a LDAP server.

After accessing through ssh I can access to phpldapadmin. I have an admin DN and a password.

What needs to be done is I have to authenticate users using ldap whenever they try to login to a website.

Website is using jaggery for the server side code. But php is okay too.

I haven't worked with ldap and ssh. So if somebody can help on this I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: what have you done so far (except asking here) ?

Comment: to use this ldap_connect(""); method I have no idea what should be between "".

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the adLDAP.php here: 
http://adldap.sourceforge.net/download.php

Then the autentication is quiet simple:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP(array('base_dn'=>'DC=domainexample,DC=suffixexample', 'account_suffix'=>'@domainexample.suffix'));
$authUser = $adldap->authenticate('user', 'password');
if ($authUser == true) {
  echo "User authenticated successfully<br>";
}
else {
  echo "User authentication unsuccessful<br>";
}
```

You have only to be careful with the DC attribution: it depends on the LDAP network.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an extension to work with LDAP. You don't need to install third-party libraries.

Work with ldap and session is what you need.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ldap.php